# Error: "component cannot define both template and templateUrl"

Tags: angular, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner, jhipster

I have some karma/phantomjs tests that used to work but now give me this error for every component even though the components do not in fact define both template and templateUrl.

I don't know whether it's related but I am also getting many reports of this error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for find()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) in /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/gba/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 4304)
```

I noticed both at the same time but I had made a lot of changes without running tests very often.

If you can think of a possible solution or even a way to debug this kind of test in my kind of project, I would be very happy.

The repository is [here](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/account/activate/activate.component.ts)

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-activate',
    templateUrl: './activate.component.html'
})
export class ActivateComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

and the compiled js looks like

```
ActivateComponent = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
        selector: 'jhi-activate',
        template: __webpack_require__("./src/main/webapp/app/account/activate/activate.component.html")
    }),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [activate_service_1.Activate,
        shared_1.LoginModalService,
        router_1.ActivatedRoute])
], ActivateComponent);
exports.ActivateComponent = ActivateComponent;
```

The test log is [here](https://gist.github.com/dancancro/32adcc263563824517fe5a8fc9604262)

```
...
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Component Tests ActivateComponent calls activate.get with the key from params FAILED
    Failed: 'ActivateComponent' component cannot define both template and templateUrl
    normalizeTemplate@spec/entry.ts:62868:209
    _loadDirectiveMetadata@spec/entry.ts:63811:92
    spec/entry.ts:64007:76
    forEach@[native code]
    loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata@spec/entry.ts:64006:48
    spec/entry.ts:75202:94
...
```

The error is thrown by [this line of Angular code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/902bb2f0262c0a68ae160641c3a3bb9736b26d4b/packages/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.ts#L70)

```
...
if (prenormData.template != null) {
  if (prenormData.templateUrl != null) {
    throw syntaxError(
        `'${stringify(prenormData.componentType)}' component cannot define both template and templateUrl`);
  }
...
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting your compiled JS files and re-compile them? Maybe you have an old js file in your compiled files for testing, creating this error.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. The problem was actually brought to my attention by Travis which starts from a clean slate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a breaking change in Angular 4.1.3 and fixed with an [update](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/133b2663956b9466257c9f5a99d872ae45ed0716) to jhipster tests by [@sendikumarn](https://github.com/sendilkumarn)